# Where to store the extension related information in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating an extension, in which I need to get a string from user and store it, so that in future I will give a suggestion through quickdropbox. Now, which is the genuine way to store the user input data? I seen the Project manager extension source. There the user input project name is stored in project.json which is located in %APPDATA%\Code\User folder. Is this right way to store?
sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want the user to *see* this string after you store (like in `User Settings`, you should use `context.globalState`. I made another extension that does something like your scenario, it's called [Tagged Comment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.tagged-comment).

This is how it stores the value:

```
context.globalState.update('lastTagged', str);
```

This is how it loads the value:

```
let lastTagged = context.globalState.get('lastTagged', '');
```

Comment: I don't want user to see these values. I will try it and let you know. I am pretty new to this. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Great! If you need more help, maybe share your extension's repo (if you can)

Comment: Sure. I am still working on the project locally. It is not in github yet. It will be soon. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Where is the location in that the extension stores those information?

Comment: It used to be stored in LocalStorage (Chrome internals), but it is now stored in the file system, inside the %appdata/Code/User/globalStorage/publisher.extensionName folder